# Can't install ubuntu.

Tags: installation, 13.04, dual-boot, live-usb

I tried installing 13.04 as a dual boot. I get the "Use the Live CD to install!" thing. Not having a live cd, I try to use a live usb. All my efforts so far seem for naught.

I did this, http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows
Then I set my bootup sequence to use the usb first.

Which to me, means I ought to be able to start up and install Ubuntu, right?

The result is the computer skips right past the usb and just loads windows7.
Am I missing something here? I must be.

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu! Is your BIOS up to date?

Answer (score 0):

I formatted my usb to exFat and started with the Pendrive universal installer.  I got a small error message saying the installation would not be bootable. Is it possible you did as well and missed the error message?
I went back and let the universal installer format the usb stick to Fat32 for me and it now works fine.

Comment: Maybe? I didn't change any settings, just let it format.